# Exporting to OBJ

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm having some trouble figuring out how I went about exporting a 3d modeling file with a texture.
I am looking to get the same 2d map as on the second picture, I'm exporting the file from Blender to Substance Painter from Blender 2.79.

Can anyone help me get back the settings I had when I did this the first time?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about reconstructing the UV map of your mesh? Or exporting the UV layout to a texture for further use in Substance Painter? The second one should be not necessary, if your model is alredy properly unwrapped, because you are going to create the textures in Substance Painter anyway.

Comment: I am trying to get the same flat texture that I have in Blender, but so far Substance has made it into a 3d version of the file. I couldn't find another way to link a picture but hope this explains it a little better: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/374370067191955459/695284977469882388/Screenshot_at_apr._02_16-47-22_copy.jpg @metaphor_set